# Querying Dynamic Per HostName

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

I have a Log Analytics Table with a column called "UserLoggingInfo", it stores users logging information per server (HostName), sometimes I get one user per server (for example, bill and bob), sometimes no users (null), and in some cases multiple users logged to the same server (johndoe, and janedone):

```
datatable(timegenerated:datetime, hostname:string, userlogginginfo:dynamic)
[
    '2023-10-05T08:00:06', 'server-01', dynamic({
        "UserName": "bill",
        "IdleTime": "01:01:00",
        "LogonTime": "2023-10-05T00:23:00.0000000Z"
    }),
    '2023-10-05T08:00:17', 'server-02', dynamic({
        "UserName": "bob",
        "IdleTime": "00:10:00",
        "LogonTime": "2023-10-05T00:24:00.0000000Z"
    }),
    '2023-10-05T08:00:28', 'server-03', dynamic(
        null
    ),
    '2023-10-05T08:00:29', 'server-04', dynamic([
        {
            "UserName": "johndoe",
            "IdleTime": "2.09:51:00",
            "LogonTime": "2023-09-30T10:45:00.0000000Z"
        },
        {
            "UserName": "janedoe",
            "IdleTime": "00:36:00",
            "LogonTime": "2023-10-05T07:23:00.0000000Z"
        }
    ])
]
| evaluate bag_unpack(userlogginginfo)
| extend UserName = userlogginginfo.UserName, IdleTime = userlogginginfo.IdleTime, LogonTime = userlogginginfo.LogonTime
```

[image: example query]

In the screenshot above I get the first two records correctly, it shows Bill and Bob, each one is returned with their UserName, IdleTime, and LogonTime respectively, the third record is wrong and shouldn't be returned because it has no value, and the last record returns nothing although it has two valid entries.

The correct query should return four records, showing UserName, IdleTime, and LogonTime, per HostName, excluding blanks, I did try several things but I can't figure out what I need to do, all I want is to get to something like this:

| HostName | UserName | IdleTime | LogonTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server-01 | bill | 01:01:00 | 2023-10-05T00:23:00.0000000Z |
| server-02 | bob | 00:10:00 | 2023-10-05T00:24:00.0000000Z |
| server-04 | johndoe | 2.09:51:00 | 2023-09-30T10:45:00.0000000Z |
| server-04 | janedoe | 00:36:00 | 2023-10-05T07:23:00.0000000Z |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a messy solution, and would probably benefit from plenty of testing.  Try [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) to split up the dynamic userlogginginfo.

```
let T = datatable(timegenerated:datetime, hostname:string, userlogginginfo:dynamic)
[
    '2023-10-05T08:00:06', 'server-01', dynamic({
        "UserName": "bill",
        "IdleTime": "01:01:00",
        "LogonTime": "2023-10-05T00:23:00.0000000Z"
    }),
    '2023-10-05T08:00:17', 'server-02', dynamic({
        "UserName": "bob",
        "IdleTime": "00:10:00",
        "LogonTime": "2023-10-05T00:24:00.0000000Z"
    }),
    '2023-10-05T08:00:28', 'server-03', dynamic(
        null
    ),
    '2023-10-05T08:00:29', 'server-04', dynamic([
        {
            "UserName": "johndoe",
            "IdleTime": "2.09:51:00",
            "LogonTime": "2023-09-30T10:45:00.0000000Z"
        },
        {
            "UserName": "janedoe",
            "IdleTime": "00:36:00",
            "LogonTime": "2023-10-05T07:23:00.0000000Z"
        }
    ])
];
let SingleT = T
| mv-expand userlogginginfo
| extend UserName = userlogginginfo.UserName, IdleTime = userlogginginfo.IdleTime, LogonTime = userlogginginfo.LogonTime
| summarize make_set(UserName), make_set(IdleTime), make_set(LogonTime) by hostname, timegenerated
| where array_length(set_LogonTime) == 1
| summarize by hostname, timegenerated, UserName = tostring(set_UserName[0]), IdleTime = tostring(set_IdleTime[0]), LogonTime = tostring(set_LogonTime[0]);
let MultipleT = T
| mv-expand userlogginginfo
| extend UserName = userlogginginfo.UserName, IdleTime = userlogginginfo.IdleTime, LogonTime = userlogginginfo.LogonTime
| summarize make_set(UserName), make_set(IdleTime), make_set(LogonTime) by hostname, timegenerated
| where array_length(set_LogonTime) >= 2
| summarize by Key = strcat(hostname, '-', timegenerated)
| join kind=leftouter (
T
| extend Key = strcat(hostname, '-', timegenerated)
) on Key
| project hostname, timegenerated, userlogginginfo
| mv-expand userlogginginfo
| extend UserName = userlogginginfo.UserName, IdleTime = userlogginginfo.IdleTime, LogonTime = userlogginginfo.LogonTime
| summarize by hostname, timegenerated, UserName = tostring(UserName), IdleTime = tostring(IdleTime), LogonTime = tostring(LogonTime);
union (SingleT), (MultipleT)
```

Comment: thanks mate but that doesn't work, I've explained the reason in my original question, the only way to make it work is to have all returning rows enclosed by square brackets [{...}] - because mv-expand will fail if your data is mixed with singletons {...} - therefore it should be [{...},{...}] or [{...}] - run the example I posted and you will understand

Comment: Aha, ok, yeah I understand the pain, thanks for the additional context.  I'll edit the original code.

Comment: I did test your solution, and it did work but it is as you said "messy", I think the best solution to avoid dealing with long and complicated queries. is to fully enclose the data with [  and ] but I guess your solution needs to be marked as final, that solved the initial problem